# I am trying to limit the number of my product list to 10

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to limit the number of products on my product list page. It should only have 10 products at max. But I am stuck how to do it can someone suggest me how to do it ? I mean a for loop or if condition or anything else which will help.

Showing details with this function

```
diplayDetails(details, index){
    return (
     <tr key={index}>
            <td>{details.product}</td>
            <td>{details.price}</td>
            <td>{details.company}</td>
            <td>{details.type}</td>
            <td>{details.expiry}</td>
            <td>{details.manufacture}</td>
        </tr>
    )

}
```

And Maping it with

```
{this.props.detail.map(this.diplayDetails)}
```

And need to add pagination in it too anything helpful regarding pagination or suggesting.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice`, so that you can limit to 10 objects.

```
{this.props.detail.slice(0, 10).map(this.diplayDetails)}
```

Comment: Yup I know about slice and it works but I have to show the other 10 in next page which would be a bit difficult. How am I suppose tell how to show next 10 on page 2 from 11 to 20

Comment: onclick of next page you have to pass range to slice(11,20) something like this, but u should pass values dynamically

Comment: Thank you for idea I have to add some logic into it and will try to figure it out!

Comment: yeah you have to put your login to show data, refer google or you can install 3rd party libraries ex ->https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate

Comment: @SaifKhan You'll be better off using a library to handle these for you. See: https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme

Comment: @Mysteryos Thank you sure I will look into it too !